# Can't access the file(Internal File Buffer NULL)

Tags: c++, c++20

I have this strange bug. I have a program which writes text to the file using the **fstream**, but the file is not being created and therefore no text is appended. When I debug my code, it shows me this:
`create_new_file = {_Filebuffer={_Pcvt=0x0000000000000000 <NULL> _Mychar=0 '\0' _Wrotesome=false ...} }.`

But whenever I use **ofstream** everything works.

Here is the code:

```
std::fstream create_new_file{ fileName.str()}; 
std::unique_ptr<std::string> changes = std::make_unique<std::string>("");
std::cin >> *changes;
create_new_file << *changes << "\n";
```

Here is the code which works:

```
std::ofstream create_new_file{ fileName.str()};
```

I have seen a similar post on Stack Overflow but the answer did not resolve my issue. I have tried adding the **std::ios::trunc** to the fstream but that did not help. But whenever I use **ofstream** everything works just as expected.

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Ok @SamVarshavchik I will edit the question to be more concise

Comment: Why do you have `std::unique_ptr<int> choice_two = std::make_unique<int>(0);` What use is a pointer to a single `int` value? Why not simply `int choice_two = 0;`? Similarly with `changes`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I will fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that for ***bidirectional file streams*** the `trunc` flag must always be explicitly specified, i.e., if you want the file content to be discarded then you must write `in | out | trunc` as the second argument as shown below.

Thus, to **solve** the problem change `std::fstream create_new_file{ fileName.str()};` to :

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv---->explicitly use trunc
std::fstream create_new_file{ "output.txt", ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ios_base::trunc};
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/GqCk18v7Q)

Answer (score 1):

[This file stream buffer `open` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) is useful. It shows a table with the different modes and what happens when they are used.

When you open a [`std::fstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) the default mode for [the constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream) is `in | out`. If we look that up in the table we see that this will *fail* if the file doesn't exist.

And you never check for failure (which you always should do).

If you only want to write to the file then use `std::ofstream` as it will open the files in `out` mode, which creates the file if it doesn't exist.

If you want to only append to the file, still use `std::ofstream` but use the mode `out | app`, which will create the file and make sure all output is appended (written to the end).